# Is there any way to read a .doc file from s3 bucket Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch a doc file from AWS S3 bucket in my rails app. Is there any way to display doc file in my view page? Or is there any gem for this? I have already made url path for file.

I am new in rails. I am also use yomu gem but I don't understand that.

Thanks

Comment: So is your specific problem reading data from S3 or displaying a doc file in a Rails view?

Comment: @Jerry I have already made url for that and its work fine. But I want to display line by line text in my view page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

By default, your browser would not let you view doc files since it wouldn't have the capability to do so. If you want to display the entire document file, you can resort to plugins that handle that for you (check out [Crocodoc](https://crocodoc.com/docs/js/) or [DocumentCloud](https://www.documentcloud.org/opensource))